# How to verify requests from Wiremock deployed to a remote host based on it's URL only?

Tags: mapping, stub, wiremock, wiremock-standalone, wiremock-record

I've implemented a custom Wiremock Server programmatically using Spring Boot and this service is deployed and running on a remote host.
The only way to access this Wiremock Server is URL provided by DevOps. Let's say *testWiremockHost.com*
All mappings are working  fine and Wiremock responds properly.

But I do have couple of questions:

1) There's no response from the Server when I try GET request on testWiremockHost.com/__admin

2) My goal is to verify requests that were sent to this Wiremock after another service is triggered, so I also need to find a way to properly define instance of this remote Wiremock in my tests in order to track incoming requests. Previously, when I tried to verify the requests from 'localhost' Wiremock server everything was just fine, but unfortunately I can't do the same for the remote one.

The latest code I've tried is the following:

```
wiremock = new WireMockBuilder().host("testWiremockHost.com").https().build();
*send request*
wiremock.verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/testEnpoint")))
```

I get the following error as a result:

```
"detail" : "Unrecognized field \"timestamp\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable"
```

I'd appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance!